# What is the significance of long maalaa (garland) worn by Krishna Chaitanya?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya, achintya-bheda-abheda

In many paintings we see that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu wears an exceptionally long garland in his neck during kirtan which extends up to the waist or knees. Also Nityananda (nitaai) is seen with such maala. Now it is a famous custom in Gaudiya vaishnava tradition.

[image]

[image]

What is this maala called?

What is story behind it?

What is its significance?